# How to exclude weekends Saturday and Sunday with adding extaDay

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below logic works for excluding saturday and sunday, remaining dates are pushing to the aray. Now I'm trying to add some extra day, here also I need to exclude saturday and sunday, but its includes saturday and sunday as well...Is there any suggestion to excludes weekends for extra day values.
Here is the sample code,

```
const extraday:number=3;
for (let i = 1 + extraday; i <= 15 + extraday; i++) {
  const dt = new Date();
  dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + i);
  if (dt.getDay() !== 6 && dt.getDay() !== 0) {// excluding weekends
    Array.push(); //
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `const extraday:number=3;` mean?

Comment: Created one variable to adding some extra days to the existing values

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. The logic looks fine to me. Can you provide more code or an example of a case that doesn't work?